# Retrofit 2.0 Beta 2 - issue with Path encoding?

Tags: android, retrofit

I recently attempted to upgrade from Retrofit 2.0 beta 1 to beta 2, upgraded all of my code, and am noticing one difference which is blocking my progress.

I have a use case where I need to provide path components dynamically to an endpoint, and I'm using a Path substitution variable for this.

For example:

```
@GET("/foo/bar/{sub}")
public Call<SomeObject> fooBar(
    @Path(value = "{sub}", encoded=true) String subPath
}
```

(apologies if syntax is less than perfect, but you get the gist).

in beta 1, I could set subPath to something like "hello/world" and the resulting endpoint would be "`/foo/bar/hello/world`"

in beta 2, regardless of the value of "encoded", it's automatically encoding the input.  so I'm getting "`/foo/bar/hello%2Fworld`"

Was there a change in the handling of pre-encoded inputs between beta 1 and beta 2, or is this simply a bug?

thanks.

Comment: You should have `@GET("foo/bar/{sub}")` and a `/` on the end of your base URL otherwise you will run into unexpected problems with Retrofit 2.0's new weird "HttpResolve" system that in my opinion causes a whole new realm of errors

Comment: yes, my "real" code is done that way, thx.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1168) with retrofit2-beta2.

The developers are looking at different solutions, but it's unclear if or when it will be addressed. In the meantime, either downgrade to beta 1 or change to using the @Url parameter instead of @Path, as suggested on Github:

```
@GET
public Call<SomeObject> fooBar(
    @Url String subPath
}
```

then:

```
fooBar("/foo/bar/" + subPath);
```

This feels very hacky to me, too. Hopefully this is fixed in future versions of retrofit.

Comment: Thanks, Luke.  I've downgraded for now, but will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, you save my time))